# True or False? Test it out!

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story, science

**Note:**

This is just a story made up by me for the puzzle. This is NOT a real assignment. Therefore, please DO NOT close this question. Thanks!

**The Puzzle:**

So, one day, my Science teacher, who loves giving us challenges and IQ questions,  gave us an interesting piece of homework. He gave us a worksheet, as follows:

[image: ws]

As I was wondering what on earth was the teacher about, I found that a note was attached to the worksheet. It says:

> This handout is worth 100% of your term grade. There needs to be ONE word written into ONE of the fields, and the others can be left blank. The word is already worth 100% of this assignment. Here is a hint: 
>  My head is fancily below,
> My body is definite, not a random thing, bro!
> My tail can be enormous or nano,
> And only with me, true or false, you will never know!

Comment: ROT13: haqrsvarq ?

Comment: @hat rot13:[abg gur nafjre, ohg jul? cbfg vg nf na nafjre fb v pna tvir lbh thvqnapr]

Comment: Just something that popped into my mind, I don't think it merits an answer (and I didn't think that it was a solution : )  ) Rot13:Urnq vf snapvyl orybj (haqre), obql vf qrsvavgr (qrsvarq). Chggvat gurz gbtrgure lbh pna trg (haqrsvarq). Haqrsvarq vf arvgure gehr abe snyfr, vg vf.. jryy.. haqrsvarq.

Comment: Holy... that was a great solution, and it definitely deserves to be an answer! However, you are right, this is not the intended answer. How does the answer relate to the ws?

Comment: That is the problem. Unless the WS is a red herring...but that does not make much sense

Comment: You can find some great and minor hints leading to the answer in the ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Inspired by @WAF who interpreted this as a Riley-style riddle, and was close on the infix]*

My head is fancily below

> *hypo* (greek prefix, eg. hypodermic goes *under* the skin)

My body is definite, not a random thing, bro!

> *the*, the definite article

My tail can be enormous or nano,

> *size*

And only with me, true or false, you will never know!

> HYPOTHESIZE

My interpretation of the worksheet is

> I will write the word in the alogrithm field. Or maybe the procedures field? Anyway, the point is, my method is just to guess. Thus the hypocrite is ME, there is no scientific process here at all.

Comment: was gonna add a hint just, but found that you have already guessed it! nice job! +1

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here. Under "Data extracted from subject" put in

> **nethistory**, as in collect the data from the subject's Internet usage, which will reveal opinions or statements they've made in the past and how consistent they are.

I interpreted the note as a Riley-style riddle, and got

My head is fancily below,

> **neth(er)**, as in "underneath" and "Netherlands"

My body is definite, not a random thing, bro!

> **this**, the singular proximate *definite* article

My tail can be enormous or nano,

> **story**, which ranges in magnitude from the epic to the utterly tiny, [especially in the context](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2009/06/12/rise-nanostory/) of 'net-propagated information.

And only with me, true or false, you will never know!

> Of course, one could look all day at what a person's online activity and still have no idea whether the things they represented were valid, but they would at least reveal how much internal agreement there was for the individual.

Comment: nice guess, got really close on the body, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> "Complain." in the Algorithm box.

because:

> The person will complain about things they don't like, therefore allowing you to see whether any of those hates are hypocritical.

Comment: Nice try but sorry no